# Problema com @extends em view no Laravel.

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou com um problema com o `@extends('layouts.template')`. Só minha view que está como index que não mostra a pagina, ao invés disso me mostra só isso `@extends('layouts.template')` na pagina. O que poderia ser?

obs: a rota está normal:

```js
Route::any('/', ["as" => "home",
    function() {
        if (Auth::guest())
            return View::make('hello');
        return Redirect::to('list');
    }
]);
```

essa é a `hello.blade.php`:

```html
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('body')

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="{{ action('TaskController@listar') }}" class="navbar-brand">TASKS LIST</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
@stop
```

e essa é `template.blade.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDoVel - Laravel To-Do</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Le styles -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }

      /* Custom container */
      .container-narrow {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 700px;
      }
      .container-narrow > hr {
        margin: 30px 0;
      }

      /* Main marketing message and sign up button */
      .jumbotron {
        margin: 60px 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .jumbotron h1 {
        font-size: 72px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
      .jumbotron .btn {
        font-size: 21px;
        padding: 14px 24px;
      }

      /* Supporting marketing content */
      .marketing {
        margin: 60px 0;
      }
      .marketing p + h4 {
        margin-top: 28px;
      }
    </style>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css') }}" />


    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/js/html5shiv.js') }}" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
                                   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">
  </head>

  <body>
<div class="container-narrow">

  <div class="masthead">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
      <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{{ URL::to('about') }}">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="muted"> Listas de Tarefas </h3>

  </div>

  <hr>

  @section('body')

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Super awesome marketing speak!</h1>
    <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="#">Sign up today</a>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="row-fluid marketing">
    <div class="span6">
      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

      <h4>Subheading</h4>
      <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  @show

  <hr>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Criado por <a href="http://www.FReNeTiC.com.br">FReNeTiC</a></p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<!-- Le javascript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.js') }}" />

<script src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="{{ Request::root() }}/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>

<!--<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>-->

@section('custom_script')
@show
```

Comment: Posta o conteúdo da das duas Views, hello.blade.php e layouts/template.blade.php

Comment: Confirme se o arquivo template.blade.php está na pasta layouts

Answer (score 8):

Verifique se os arquivos tem a extensão **.blade.php** e não apenas **.php**

Para suportar outros sistemas de Template o Laravel permite views personalizadas, que não usam Blade, esse é o caso do arquivo **hello.php**, que não usa o Blade, para que seu `@extends()` funcione você deve renomeá-lo para **hello.blade.php**

O método `View::make()` consegue identificar as duas extensões, não sendo necessário alterar nada em sua Rota.

**Edição:**
O problema era devido a codificação do arquivo, o Laravel reconheceu algum caractere antes de extends("layout.layout"), e por isso não renderizava.

Passo a Passo para solução do problema:

1) Verificar se o arquivo tem extensão **.blade.php**

2) Certificar-se que **@extends('nomedolayout')** seja a primeira instrução da View.

3) Recriar o arquivo, para evitar algum possível problema de codificação, que impeça o @extends de ser reconhecido como o início do arquivo.

Comment: tem sim..... e seu eu retiro e @extends() e insiro um codigo html do template no hello.blade.php dá certo.... já nos outros arquivos funciona blzinha o @extends()

Comment: return View::make('hello'); Redireciona para a View de Exemplo que vem junto ao Laravel, verifique se o arquivo existe: app/views/hello.php

Answer (score 1):

No seu `template.blade.php` você utilizou:

```php
@section('body')
```

e o correto seria

```php
@yield('body')
```

Caso queira usar com section, na sua view que estende o `template.blade.php` você usará o

```php
@section('body')
@parent
//Conteudo da Seção
@stop
```

http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating

Comment: parece até marcação.. mas a view de login continua blz mesmo depois da edição que vc me sujeriu mas a hello.blade.php só me retrna no browser @extends('layouts.template').....

Comment: Posta os dois arquivos no http://paste.laravel.com/ e passa o link para darmos uma olhada.

Comment: tá na mão Flavio    http://paste.laravel.com/1fA8

Comment: Cara fiz um simples teste aqui:
utilizando o arquivo como hello.php dá o problema que você relatou, já utilizando o arquivo como hello.blade.php funciona, dá uma olhada se você não está com os 2 arquivos:
hello.php e hello.blade.php, se estiverem na mesma pasta, apaga o errado ou renomeia ele.

Comment: Vei eu olhei se tinha 2 arquivos, renomeei troquei no arquivo de rotas mudei de @yield('body') pra @yield('content')... e nada....    ai decidi copiar o codigo do arquivo apagar ele e criar um novo arquivo com o mesmo codigo   pois vc acredita que deu certo.....  vai entender né........   Flavio muito obrigado mesmo brother.... sem esquecer do Guilherme e o Hernandes também.... vlw mestres

Comment: @henrique, isso acontece pois seu editor deve ter acrescentado algum caractere ao início do arquivo (BOM talvez).